# in-app purchase rejection and new ipa

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am working in an iOS application with in-app purchase for a client, i have submit to him the .ipa and he want to do the submission process. The application was rejected.
the following message from apple

From Apple. Missing IAPs

We are unable to complete the review of your app since one or more of your In App Purchases have not been submitted for review.

Please be sure to take action and submit your In App Purchases AND upload a new binary in iTunes Connect. Learn more about submitting In App Purchases for review in the iTunes Connect Developer Guide.

Once you've submitted your In App Purchases and uploaded a new binary, we can proceed with your review.

My questions is Should i create a new .ipa and send it to my client and then he can put the in-app purchase to "wait for review" or should can he use the old .ipa ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client has to make sure he properly set up IAPs, made them ready for review and **then properly included them in new app version** he's trying to upload in iTunesConnect.

Comment: you mean that i should create a new .ipa even if i have tested it with the older .ipa ?

Comment: No, you don't have to rebuild the project if IAPs work correctly and you tested it, he can upload your old build.